# Calculating total quantity of equipments for a date range

Tags: php, mysql

Project: I am working on a project which is about some rooms and equipments using in the rooms. The software is about scheduling the equipments in the rooms. In other words, it is a reservation software that reserves selected equipments in separate rooms for needed dates and times ranges. I have many tables in MYsSQL database working with Php but I will mention the tables my question is about. The tables I will relate my questions are equipment table (Table A), schedule table (Table B) and equipments using in the related schedule (Table C).

Table A: equipment list table

```
eqid   | eqName    | available| 

1      |  book     |   90     |      

2      |  pen      |   82     | 

3      |  computer |   25     |
```

In table A; eqid represents unique id of an equipment, eqName represents name of an equipment, available represents total available equipments existing.

Table B: schedule table

```
scheduleid | startDate  | endDate    | startTime | endTime  |  office  |

1          | 2012-08-27 | 2012-08-27 | 08:30:00  | 10:00:00 |  room1   |

2          | 2012-08-27 | 2012-08-27 | 09:30:00  | 11:00:00 |  room3   |

3          | 2012-08-28 | 2012-08-30 | 08:30:00  | 12:00:00 |  room2   |

4          | 2012-08-29 | 2012-08-31 | 11:30:00  | 14:00:00 |  room1   |

5          | 2012-08-28 | 2012-08-28 | 10:30:00  | 14:00:00 |  room3   |

6          | 2012-08-27 | 2012-08-30 | 08:30:00  | 10:00:00 |  room4   |

7          | 2012-08-27 | 2012-08-27 | 10:30:00  | 12:00:00 |  room4   |    

8          | 2012-08-27 | 2012-08-30 | 08:30:00  | 11:00:00 |  room6   |

9          | 2012-08-27 | 2012-08-27 | 10:30:00  | 12:00:00 |  room5   |
```

In table B; scheduleid represents unique id for a schedule, startDate and endDate are date range for a schedule, startTime and endTime time range for a schedule, office means that where the schedule will take place. Let me give an example here. Scheduleid 1 means there is a reservation on 27th of august 2012, Monday and it is from 08.30 to 10:00. As it start and end on same day this is just one day reservation in room1. However, Scheduleid 3 means there is a reservation starts on 28th of august 2012, Tuesday and goes on until 30th of august 2012, Thursday at 08:30-12:00... in other words, it lasts for 3 days and everyday from 08:30 to 12:00... So there is a reservation from Tuesday to Thursday at 08:30 to 12:00 in room2... I hope this is clear.

Table C: equipments using in the related schedule

```
Autoid  | scheduleid |  eqid   | amountInSch|

1       |     1      |   1     |      2     |      

2       |     1      |   2     |      3     |  

3       |     1      |   3     |      1     |  

4       |     2      |   1     |      1     |  

5       |     2      |   2     |      1     |  

6       |     2      |   3     |      2     |  

7       |     3      |   2     |      1     | 

8       |     3      |   3     |      3     |  

9       |     4      |   2     |      1     |  

10      |     4      |   3     |      1     |  

11      |     5      |   1     |      1     |  

12      |     6      |   1     |      1     | 

13      |     6      |   3     |      2     |  

14      |     6      |   2     |      4     |  

15      |     7      |   1     |      5     |  

16      |     7      |   2     |      6     |  

17      |     8      |   2     |      1     | 

18      |     9      |   1     |      8     |  

19      |     9      |   2     |      5     |  

20      |     9      |   3     |      6     |
```

In table C: Autoid represents unique automatic id generated by auto-increment, scheduleid comes from Table B, eqid comes from Table A, amountInSch represents how many (amount) equipment will use in the related schedule. I want to give an example here. Scheduleid 1 in Table C, there are 3 rows. This means that scheduleid 1 related in TAble B will use 2 books (eqid 1), 3 pens (eqid 2) and 1 computer (eqid 3) in room1 specified dates and times in table B . Another example is that scheduleid 3 in Table C is related 2 rows. It means that 1 pen (eqId 2) and 3 computers (eqId 3) will be using in room2 from  27th to 30th of august 2012 everyday from 08:30 to 12:00.

The above is the explanation and give some information about the project. The table rows are not permanent. When you make a reservation, there will be a new row in Table B and if it is selected an equipment, there will be new rows in table C...

The Question:

I want to calculate left amount of a specific equipment when I supply eqId, startDate, endDate, startTime and endTime...

An example:

eqId:  1 (book)

startDate: 2012-08-27

endDate:   2012-08-27

startTime: 08:30:00

endTime:   12:00:00

Result should be: 14 books used in schedule and 76 left available books

Because: if you look scheduleIds and related eqIds, you will only see 1, 2, 6, 7, 9 scheduleIds related to my query(dates and eqId). If you sum the all amount of related in Table C, you will get the wrong result. In other words, related amounts for eqId(1-book) and for 1, 2, 6, 7, 9 scheduleIds are 2, 1, 1, 5, 8 respectively. So if you sum them you will get 17 which is wrong. Because, 1 and 9 schedule don't intersect each other in terms of start and end Times, and 6 and 7 don't intersect each other either. as a result of them 2 stays lonely and can be count separately. We must consider 1 and 9 as summed 8 because 8 is bigger than 2. it is same for  6 and 7, considered as 5 because of 5 is bigger than 1...

So folks! I am not sure how I can sum/ this in programming algorithm. Is there a way to do in SQL or do I have to use PHP and Mysql together? and How?

Cheers!

## [*SQLFiddle Records*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa8cf)

Comment: Why have you separated your start date and start time into two fields, rather than using DATETIME items?  Same question for end date and time. You may have a good reason; if so please explain. Otherwise you might consider consolidating the date and time data.  Thanks for the sqlfiddle records!

Comment: @OllieJones If I had used DATETIME, it could mean that from startDateTime to endDateTime. An example is 2012-08-27 | 2012-08-28 | 08:30:00  | 10:00:00 means on Monday and Tuesday only from 08:30 to 10:00. However If I has used DATE Time like 2012-08-27 08:30:00 | 2012-08-28 10:00:00, it would mean that from Monday 08:30 to Tuesday 10:00. So it includes all day, whereas I wan some specific hours in a date range. That's because I used different fields.

Comment: Why is the correct answer in your example not 13, given that the books used in schedules 7 and 9 can also fully satisfy those required in schedules 1, 2 and 6?

Comment: For querying you have given start time: 8:30 and end time: 10:00 then why are you simply even looking at scheduleids 7 and 9 in Table B.

Comment: @eggyal you cannot use the same book in 1, 2 and 6 at the same time, can you? Plese look at the start end endTimes for 1,2 and 6... after the endTime you can give the books another room so they are in separate rooms.

Comment: @shubhansh you are right. I wanted to tell 12:00:00 in the example, I edited it now. So thank you for your warning...

Comment: @deepnote: But schedules 7 and 9 (which overlap) require 13 books between them.  Those 13 books can fully satisfy the four books required across schedules 1, 2 and 6 (which overlap eachother, but not schedules 7 or 9).  So only 13 books are required in total, no?

Comment: I agree with eggyal.  It seems like only 13 books should be required.

Comment: @eggyal you are right! in that case it is true but I wanted write 11:00:00 as endTime for 2. I am editing it now

Comment: @Tom it should have been 11:00:00 for 2. You are right. As it is messy question in my mind, I cannot think very well...

Answer (score 1):

I started with the following SQL to gather all date ranges that intersect with the given range:

```
SELECT MAX(available) - IFNULL(SUM(amountInSch), 0)
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table3 USING (eqid)
LEFT JOIN Table2 USING (scheduleid)
WHERE DATE(startDate) <= '2012-08-27' AND DATE(endDate) >= '2012-08-27'
  AND endTime > '08:30' AND startTime < '12:00'
  AND eqid = 1
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa8cf/103)

This is only the first part. Next up you have to work out the possible overlaps; this wouldn't be practical to do with SQL, so I would suggest to do this in PHP.

The generic algorithm I would pick is unfortunately O(n**2), it goes like this:

- create a timeline (demarcated by each day) with time as the horizontal axis
- iterate over every date/time range and mark the time of its left and right edge to create time segments of every possible permutation.
- using the segments, you sum vertically for overlaps and you take the daily maximum across.

Hope that helps.

Comment: dear Jack, Thank you very much for your effort but the answer as you find is wrong. it is supposed to be 76... I am still trying how to manage to do this algorithm...

Comment: @deepnote okay, according to you, which schedules should have been matched? manual work leads me to schedules: 1, 2, 6, 7, 9

Comment: hmm I didn't check the time overlaps, I'm afraid that logic may have to be handled by PHP.

Comment: do you have any idea how to handle the time overlaps in PHP? that would be really helpful thanks

Comment: @deepnote yes, i've added an algorithm that should give you enough inspiration :)

Comment: That's what I have thought! Thank you... I am not sure if I will be able to do in Php... Would you please code the algorithm for me?

Comment: @deepnote I think you'd have more luck starting a bounty for that :)