# php mysql time bookings

Tags: php, mysql

I am busy with a booking system and need to check if 2 times overlap. This is my query so far and if the results is > 1 then there is already a booking during that time. I am getting an error/warning when trying to get the number of rows. (see below) Because of this, my count is not calculated and the booking is made. Please help. Also , I am using time types in my database (starttime and endttime) but the post variables are string time, hence why I used strtotime(). Please see the error below:

```
$mystarttime = '07:00:00';
$myendtime = '08:00:00';
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 WHERE
            (
            (strtotime($mystarttime) < starttime AND strtotime($myendtime) > starttime)
            OR
            (strtotime($mystarttime) > starttime AND strtotime($myendtime) < endtime)
            OR
            (strtotime($mystarttime) > starttime AND strtotime($mystarttime) < endtime)
            OR
            (starttime < strtotime($mystarttime)  AND  starttime > strtotime($myendtime))
            OR
            (starttime > strtotime($mystarttime) AND endtime < strtotime($myendtime))
            OR
            (starttime > strtotime($mystarttime) AND endtime < strtotime($mystarttime))
            OR
            (strtotime($mystarttime) = starttime)
            OR
            (strtotime($mystarttime) = endtime)
            OR
            (strtotime($myendtime) = starttime)
            OR
            (strtotime($myendtime) = endtime)
            OR
            (starttime = strtotime($mystarttime))
            OR
            (starttime = strtotime($myendtime))
            OR
            (endtime = strtotime($mystarttime))
            OR
            (endtime = strtotime($myendtime))
            )
            AND
            hairdresserid = $myhairdresserid 
            AND
            date = $mydate";

            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            //Mysql_num_row is counting table row
            $count  = mysql_num_rows($result)or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . $sql);
```

Warning message I get:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/makebooking.php on line 165
```

`Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to` `your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':00:00) < starttime AND strtotime(08:00:00) > starttime) OR ' at line 3SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE ( (strtotime(07:00:00) < starttime AND strtotime(08:00:00) > starttime) OR (strtotime(07:00:00) > starttime AND strtotime(08:00:00) < endtime) OR (strtotime(07:00:00) > starttime AND strtotime(07:00:00) < endtime) OR (starttime < strtotime(07:00:00) AND starttime > strtotime(08:00:00)) OR (starttime > strtotime(07:00:00) AND endtime < strtotime(08:00:00)) OR (starttime > strtotime(07:00:00) AND endtime < strtotime(07:00:00)) OR (strtotime(07:00:00) = starttime) OR (strtotime(07:00:00) = endtime) OR (strtotime(08:00:00) = starttime) OR (strtotime(08:00:00) = endtime) OR (starttime = strtotime(07:00:00)) OR (starttime = strtotime(08:00:00)) OR (endtime = strtotime(07:00:00)) OR (endtime = strtotime(08:00:00)) ) AND hairdresserid = 12 AND date = 2012-01-25`

### EDIT #1:

```
Query failed: SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE ( (1359118800 < starttime AND 1359122400 > starttime) OR (1359118800 > starttime AND 1359122400 < endtime) OR (1359118800 > starttime AND 1359118800 < endtime) OR (starttime < 1359118800 AND starttime > 1359122400) OR (starttime > 1359118800 AND endtime < 1359122400) OR (starttime > 1359118800 AND endtime < 1359118800) OR (1359118800 = starttime) OR (1359118800 = endtime) OR (1359122400 = starttime) OR (1359122400 = endtime) OR (starttime = 1359118800) OR (starttime = 1359122400) OR (endtime = 1359118800) OR (endtime = 1359122400) ) AND hairdresserid = 12 AND date = 2012-01-25
```

### EDIT #2:

```
Query failed: SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE ( (1359118800 < starttime AND 1359122400 > starttime) OR (1359118800 > starttime AND 1359122400 < endtime) OR (1359118800 > starttime AND 1359118800 < endtime) OR (starttime < 1359118800 AND starttime > 1359122400) OR (starttime > 1359118800 AND endtime < 1359122400) OR (starttime > 1359118800 AND endtime < 1359118800) OR (1359118800 = starttime) OR (1359118800 = endtime) OR (1359122400 = starttime) OR (1359122400 = endtime) OR (starttime = 1359118800) OR (starttime = 1359122400) OR (endtime = 1359118800) OR (endtime = 1359122400) ) AND hairdresserid = 12 AND date = 2012-01-25
```

### EDIT #3:

```
Query failed: SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE ( ('07:00:00' < starttime AND '08:00:00' > starttime) OR ('07:00:00' > starttime AND '08:00:00' < endtime) OR ('07:00:00' > starttime AND '07:00:00' < endtime) OR (starttime < '07:00:00' AND starttime > '08:00:00') OR (starttime > '07:00:00' AND endtime < '08:00:00') OR (starttime > '07:00:00' AND endtime < '07:00:00') OR ('07:00:00' = starttime) OR ('07:00:00' = endtime) OR ('08:00:00' = starttime) OR ('08:00:00' = endtime) OR (starttime = '07:00:00') OR (starttime = '08:00:00') OR (endtime = '07:00:00') OR (endtime = '08:00:00') ) AND hairdresserid = 12 AND date = 2012-01-25
```

### EDIT #4:

```
Query failed: SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE ( ('07:00:00' < starttime AND '08:00:00' > starttime) OR ('07:00:00' > starttime AND '08:00:00' < endtime) OR ('07:00:00' > starttime AND '07:00:00' < endtime) OR (starttime < '07:00:00' AND starttime > '08:00:00') OR (starttime > '07:00:00' AND endtime < '08:00:00') OR (starttime > '07:00:00' AND endtime < '07:00:00') OR ('07:00:00' = starttime) OR ('07:00:00' = endtime) OR ('08:00:00' = starttime) OR ('08:00:00' = endtime) OR (starttime = '07:00:00') OR (starttime = '08:00:00') OR (endtime = '07:00:00') OR (endtime = '08:00:00') ) AND hairdresserid = 12 AND date = '2012-01-25'
```

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109737/calculating-total-quantity-of-equipments-for-a-date-range/12210430#12210430) will help you make a better query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is a PHP function. You cannot write it in SQL statement. Instead, concat it.

If your field `starttime` is **integer** data type, I would do this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tbl_name2."
        WHERE startime > '".strtotime($mystarttime)."' 
        AND starttime < '".strtotime($myendtime)."' 
        AND date = '".$mydate."'";
```

If your field `starttime` is **time** data type (for eample, 00:00:00), I would do this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tbl_name2."
        WHERE startime > '".$mystarttime."' 
        AND starttime < '".$myendtime."' 
        AND date = '".$mydate."'";
```

About string quotes in PHP, the better practice is to use single quotes if you concatenate strings and use double quotes in inner. The single-quoted strings are probably faster at runtime because they do not need to be parsed.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$tbl_name2.'
        WHERE startime > "'.$mystarttime.'"
        AND starttime < "'..$myendtime.'"
        AND date = "'.$mydate.'"';
```

Comment: starttime and endtime are both normal strings. such as $starttime = '07:00:00';

Comment: I am thinking of formatting that as a time variable which mysql can understand somehow.

Comment: @Janpan, I mean the data type in the table.

Comment: the data type in the table is of type TIME. And the values I am comparing it with is of type String. I need the string to become time so that time > time etc will work.

Comment: @Janpan, If type TIME, you would not need `strtotime()` like in my second query.

Comment: I did that, however, it outputs the timestamp or a number similar to 1935765876 .

Comment: @Janpan, I see you are still using strtotime() in your query. The numbers (e.g, 1359118800, etc.) are generated from strtotime(). Anyway, try to wrap single quotes around all time and date fields. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I tried the second example you have, but it still gives an error. See edit 3 above.

Comment: @Japan, quotes for the date field.

Comment: Did that, still get query failed. sigh. please see Edit 4 above.

Comment: Check the query error - if( ! $result = mysql_query($sql)) die(mysql_error());

Comment: That is what I am doing, here is my query :$count  = mysql_num_rows($result)or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . $sql);

Comment: Yes, according to your code, if `mysql_num_rows($result)` return 0, it will go `die()`. That's mean your query did not fail. Instead, use `if( ! $result = mysql_query($sql) ) die(mysql_error().$sql);` and remove `die()` in your `$count` line.

Comment: sweeet, seems like I got confused after all the errors and warnings. Thanks for your help man, really an example of why stackoverflow works. Cheers

Comment: You're welcome. See also better quote string practice in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `strtotime` function in mysql so you'll have to do the following

Either remove all the `strtotime` from the query and add it to `$mystarttime` (`$mystarttime = strtotime('07:00:00');`)
Or replace every occurence of `strtotime($myendtime)` with `".strtotime($myendtime)."`.

And you can write the query much easier I think, you could try something like the following:

```
"SELECT * FROM " . $tbl_name2 . " WHERE 
(starttime BETWEEN " . $mystarttime . " AND " . $myendtime . ") 
AND 
(endtime BETWEEN "    . $mystarttime . " AND " . $myendtime . ") 
AND 
hairdresserid = " . $myhairdresserid . "
AND
date = '" . $mydate . "';"
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked, however , it does not convert the time correctly. see the edit #1 above.

Comment: you're at least missing single quotes surrounding the date `$mydate`.

Comment: nope no error message. I don;t think the single quotes matters.

Comment: Yes they do matter to sql, 2012-01-25 is a string, so it has to be marked as such.
Besides, you should execute the query in a mysql browser then to get some more information about the error. MySQL almost always provides some more information.

Comment: @Janpan, It depends on your field data types. Check my answer.